# Adding regression line to plotted matrix

Tags: r, plot, graph

How do I add a regression line to this graph? I tried abline() but it seems to only work with dataframes and I'm working with a matrix.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAeyL.png

This is my code for the graph:

```
plot(Extended[,1], Extended[,14], xlim=c(1877, 2017), ylim=c(-12, 15), pch=19, col = 'blue')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in general easier with ggplot.

```
library(ggplot2)
Ex <- as.data.frame(Extended); 
names(Ex) <- paste0('V', 1:ncol(Ex)); 
ggplot(Ex, aes(x = V1,  y = V14)) + 
  geom_point(size = 4, col = 'blue') + 
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm') + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1877, 2017), 
                  ylim = c(-12, 15))
```

For base method there are myriad ways of visualizing the effects. The `effects` package is a very general way of doing this. The way this works is by using the `predictorEffect` function and specifying which effect to plot.

```
library(effects)
data(mtcars)
model <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)
plot(predictorEffect('hp', model))
```

[image: effects-plot]

The effects package has some very general implementations that can do quite a lot of things. I'd recommend reading the vignettes to get an idea how the package works.

For a manual base plot version we could do something like:

```
mtcars[, c('fit', 'lwr', 'upr')] <- predict(model, interval = 'predict')
mtcars <- mtcars[order(mtcars$hp),]
plot(y = mtcars$mpg, x = mtcars$hp, 
     pch=19, col = 'blue')
lines(y = mtcars$fit, x = mtcars$hp, col = 'green')
lines(y = mtcars$upr, x = mtcars$hp, col = 'red')
lines(y = mtcars$lwr, x = mtcars$hp, col = 'red')
```

[image: base-plot]